# fsfreeze blocking mounted blob device in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

### Some context

I've been working with two separate Ubuntu Linux VMs (Ubuntu 14.04.3 kernel 3.13.0-67-generic hosted in Azure), each one having attached an extra virtual harddrive. 
Inside these drives I have huge files which are encrypted / decrypted with cryptsetup and then mounted as a regular FS.
Also, within Azure I had configured a backup procedure which ran every 30 mins or so. 
This setup has been working for 6+ months with no problem so far until Feb/10/2016 approx.

### Problem

Any process requiring access to any of the files in the decrypted/mounted volume has become unresponsive. The processes (eg: mysqld) are still running. Going through the list of running processes I spotted the following one (which I did not start BTW):

```
<PID> <PPID>   fsfreeze -f <path_to_my_mounted_device>
```

Any attempt to kill this process (sudo kill -9 ) would fail. 
Looking at the parent process it seemed to be a Microsoft backup task (a python script). 
In order to get my services back to work I have to reboot the VM.

This problem **seems** to solve by getting rid of the Azure's Backup service.

### Question

1. Did anyone run into this issue lately?
2. Is there any work around to continue having backup routines without having the procedure to completely prevent any access to the file system?
3. Does anyone know if Azure's Backup service is really causing the fsfreeze command to run?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes, the vmbackup would call the fsfreeze.
could you please share the disk layout with us.
so I can repro it in our environment.

also please share the logs out.
/var/log/waagent.log
/var/log/azure/*

Answer (score 0):

recently we find one issue in our backup extension,
when there's network issue. our extensio would cause the vm to freeze.
and it's fixed, new extension would be published soon.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better than restart the vm is to unfreeze the file system with "fsfreeze --unfreeze"